# Update active flow via sfdx

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

Is it possible to change the status of an active flow to inactive via sfdx? I tried it with
`sfdx force:data:record:update` and following query:

`SELECT ActiveVersionId, MasterLabel, DeveloperName from FlowDefinition WHERE ActiveVersion.Status='Active'`
but this one throws floowing error

```
ERROR running force:data:record:update:  The requested resource does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to deploy the Flow metadata changing the status attribute. Using `sfdx force:source:deploy` for example

Comment: I know, but this one throws the above error `sfdx force:data:record:update -s FlowDefinition -i <ID> -v "ActiveVersion.Status='Obsolote' MasterLabel='New Lead' DeveloperName='New_Lead' " -u <targetOrg>-t`

Comment: @Asadiya actually you're trying to update the underlying metadata record, I mean really deploying the component metadata, I've updated the answer to reflect my point

Answer (score 1):

You cannot activate/deactivate flows using Metadata API.  Check limitation details [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DhHjAAK).    However,  previously flows were always deployed as inactive and now you can deploy a new active version of flow via Metadata API/Change sets and please note this setting doesn't appear in non-production orgs (such as scratch, sandbox, and developer orgs).  Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_deploy_as_active.htm&type=5&release=216).

Thanks